# PIL does not visualise FITS files

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, astropy, astronomy

I will start this post by saying that although I can code a little, I'm not super good at it yet so apologies if the answer is really obvious and I do not see it.

I have a series of .fits files that I need to visualise through PIL. I wanted to do it in an easy manner by just using the fact that PIL has support for FITS.

The images used are from the WISE database for the M1 nebulae.

When I tried to run the following code, all I get is a grainy image:

```
from PIL import Image

fits_file = Image.open('image.fits')
fits_file.show()
```

If I try to read it through the Astropy fits module instead, it sometimes returns the right image and sometimes returns a white image (which I believe is due to the min/max being over 255).

```
from astropy.io import fits
from PIL import Image

fits_file = fits.open('image.fits')
fits_img = fits_file[0].data
pil_img = Image.fromarray(fits_img)
pil_img.show()
```

Am I missing something as to why I cannot get all of the images to visualise correctly?

EDIT: I have decided to provide the images I get with my codes.

The first block of code shows the following image:
[image: Grainy image]

The second block of code shows the following image:
[image: Blank image]

The original image as visualised by astropy + matplotlib:
[image: Original image]

EDIT 2: Following a link provided in the comments I changed the second code to:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from PIL import Image

fits_file = fits.open('image.fits')
fits_img = fits_file[0].data
pil_img = Image.fromarray(fits_img, mode="F")
pil_img.show()
```

This returns the same image as the first code.

Comment: Maybe the image you're using is grainy?  can you provide an example of an image that you're struggling with?

Comment: Check that the files you are having trouble with are correctly viewable in some other FITS viewer and examine their headers to see what gives - there are plenty to choose from (many free and capable) at [NASA fits archive](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_viewer.html)

Comment: @MartinBrown The images are all perfectly visible with astropy + matplotlib, however I need to use PIL to visualise them

Comment: @JeffUK The image is not grainy, I have just added the image outputs to the original post now

Comment: I think you need to use some other tool to examine the headers and see if you can construct a FITS file that the PIL file loader can cope with. I'd suggest scaling it to an 8 bit image and then  feeding it that. Default appears to be 8bit monochrome. There must be some config setting to tell it that the data is 16bit integer somewhere. This [PIL link](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1514) might be relevant.

Comment: use a library specializing in reading of FITS files? don't expect PIL to handle such niche file types correctly

Comment: Please share the actual FITS file you are working with - either a link to something I can readily access on NASA site or via Dropbox or Google Drive or Github.

Comment: Ah, that's not a 'Grainy image' that's 'Random noise',  a very different question. Looks like PIL is entirely failing to parse that file format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is not possible to debug without an image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell apologies for the late response about the FITS files. I searched for "M1" with the preset parameters and downloaded the files, all from this website: https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/wise

Comment: @MartinBrown Thank you for the PIL link, I was tinkering for a bit and I believe I may have found an error in PIL where it does not visualise float32 images correctly, as I manually defined the float32 mode in Image.fromarray() and it returns the same error as the Image.open(), however after doing a very rough (I hope correct) 8-bit conversion, it suddenly visualizes it with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think PIL has a bug and reads the FITS file with the wrong byte order. If I open the file, convert to Numpy array, swap the byte order to accommodate the bug and then scale and save as PNG it works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Oopen sample FITS image and convert to Numpy array
im = Image.open('sample.fits')
na = np.array(im)

# BYTESWAP FOR SOME UNKNOWN REASON
nb = na.byteswap()

# Scale data to range 0..65535 so we can see it
nc = (nb - nb.min()) * 65535/(nb.max() - nb.min())

# Save as 16-bit PNG
Image.fromarray(nc.astype(np.uint16)).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fix, this indeed also works for me! Do you think this is something worth reporting on the PIL GitHub?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea. You can click `Share` beneath your question to get a link and then add that link for the developers to see what's going on.

Comment: The reason you have to byteswap is because the raw data in FITS files is stored bigendian, always  I have no idea what Image.open does with FITS files though. I didn't even know PIL supported them directly.

Comment: @Iguananaut Thank you for your insights. Hopefully OP will raise issue and the Pillow developers will see your comment.